# select only first row of an sub table join

Tags: mysql

am having the table **goodsbooking_tbl**
[image: goodsBooking_tbl-structure]
[image: goodsbooking_subTbl]

**what i need:** need to select the rows inn main table with some ids, and also select only the first row of the main table id..

was tryed this..

```
SELECT a.idgoodsbooking_tbl, a.consignorId, a.ConsigneeId, date_format(a.bookingDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as GCdate, 
a.GCNumber, a.frieghtTotal, a.paymentType,b.description FROM goodsbooking_tbl a 
 JOIN goodsbooking_subtbl b ON a.idgoodsbooking_tbl=b.idgoodsbooking_tbl WHERE a.idgoodsbooking_tbl in (1,2);
```

it returns [image]

i need only the first row from the subtable ie.

```
1        3                1        01-01-2015     GC-15-01     15000.00     safdasf
2        2                1        01-01-2015     GC-15-02     350.00       sdafsaf
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: add `limit 1` at the end of the query.

Comment: add "limit 1" at the end of statement.

Comment: sorry , i need all the rows from main table and only to restrict the sub table rows..

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (and you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: replace `SELECT a.idgoodsbooking_tbl` with `SELECT distinct b.idgoodsbooking_tbl`

Comment: sorry it returns the same result.. @PrerakSola

Comment: see the edited comment. Try if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want only one column, I think the easiest way might be a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.idgoodsbooking_tbl, a.consignorId, a.ConsigneeId,
       date_format(a.bookingDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as GCdate, 
       a.GCNumber, a.frieghtTotal, a.paymentType,
       (SELECT b.description
        FROM goodsbooking_subtbl b
        WHERE  a.idgoodsbooking_tbl = b.idgoodsbooking_tbl
        ORDER BY idgoodbooking_subtbl DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as description
FROM goodsbooking_tbl a
WHERE a.idgoodsbooking_tbl in (1,2);
```